# check if array contains values, if not then add to arraylist - Concurrent Modification Exception - Java

Tags: java, arrays, iterator

I am passing a `String name` to a method, if that `name` isn't in the array then it gets added.

> I tried this first but got Concurrent Modification Exception

```
List<String> people = new ArrayList<>();

public void addName(String name) {
    if (people.isEmpty()) {
        people.add(name);
    } else {
        for (String s : people) {
            if (s.equals(name)) {
                System.out.println("dont add");
            } else {
                people.add(name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After reading on forums I learned you have to use iterator to avoid this. I tried it and fixed the `Concurrent Modification Exception`, but the player gets added even though I stated them not to be added if they exist in the array, I do get this output "name exists" when I pass a name already existing in the list, but then it runs "name added" as well so dont understand why this is happening

```
if (people.isEmpty()) {
    people.add(name);
} else {
    String name2 = null;
    for (Iterator<String> it = people.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        String element = it.next();
        if (element.equals(name)) {
            String message = "name exists";
            System.out.println(message);
            name2 = null;
        } else if (!element.equals(name)) {
            System.out.println("Name added");
            name2 = name;
        }
    }
    if (name2 != null) {
        people.add(name2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, can't you use `people.contains(name);`?

Comment: that means if a name is "don" then you got a another name as "donkey" they will match, I only want to not add the name if the same name exists in the array

Comment: “After reading on forums I learned you have to use iterator to avoid this.”  Those forums were wrong.  A for-each loop is functionally identical to using an Iterator, and in both cases, you cannot modify a Collection while iterating over it.  Go with blahfunk’s suggestion and use the `contains` method.  Your entire addName method can be implemented with just two lines of code.  (Regarding your comment:  Collection.contains is not related to String.contains in any way.  Collection.contains uses equality, not a substring test.)

Comment: @CookieMonster That is not true. It is true if you were checking that an individual string contains another string, but you are checking to see if the ArrayList contains it, not the individual string.

Comment: @blahfunk thanks, i was a bit confused at start about contains but works well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it simply by:

```
public void addName(String name) {
    if (!people.contains(name)) {
        people.add(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to re-invent a set.

```
Set<String> names = new TreeSet<>(); // Or set of your choice
names.add("Joe"); // Set contents ["Joe"]
names.add("Bob"); // Set contents ["Joe", "Bob"];
names.add("Joe"); // Set contents ["Joe", "Bob"];
```

If you want to have the printlines

```
if (names.add(name) {
  System.out.println("Added name " + name);
} else {
  System.out.println("Already added " + name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you need to break out of your loop once you find that the name already exists. Otherwise `name2` might get set to `null` and then set to a non-null value again.

For example:

```
           for (Iterator<String> it = people.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                String element = it.next();
                if (element.equals(name)) {
                    String message = "name exists";
                    System.out.println(message);
                    name2 = null;
                    break;
                } else if(element.equals(name)==false) {
                    System.out.println("Name added");
                    name2 = name;
                }
            }
```

But do have a look at `contains` since this is a much much cleaner approach!